# curl command works but guzzle failed

Tags: php, curl, httpclient, guzzle

I'm using the below guzzle code to create the customer using Odoo API

```
$headers = ['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json','Content-Type'     => 'application/json','Access-Token' => $access_token]];
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client($headers);                
$response = $client->request('POST', $url.'?magento_id='.$magento_id.'&odoo_email='.$magento_email.'&data_json='.json_encode($magentoCustomer));
echo $response->getStatusCode();exit;
```

But I get the below error in the error log

```
error: `POST https://domain/api/res.partner/magento_update_partner_single?magento_id=28&odoo_email=mail@mail.com&data_json=%7B%22customer%22:%7B%22id%22:28,%22group_id%22:1,%22created_in%22:%22Default%20Store%20View%22,%22dob%22:%22string%22,%22email%22:%22mail@mail.com%22,%22firstname%22:%22Bilal%22,%22lastname%22:%22Usean%22,%22middlename%22:%22%22,%22store_id%22:1,%22website_id%22:1,%22addresses%22:%5B%7B%22id%22:113,%22customer_id%22:28,%22country_id%22:%22US%22,%22street%22:%5B%227000%20Central%20Parkway,%20Suite%20220%22%5D,%22telephone%22:%22+1%20678-648-7722%22,%22postcode%22:%2230328%22,%22city%22:%22Atlanta%22,%22region%22:%7B%22region_code%22:%22GA%22%7D,%22firstname%22:%22Bilal%20Usean%22,%22lastname%22:%22Bilal%20Usean%22,%22middlename%22:%22%22%7D%5D,%22disable_auto_group_change%22:0%7D,%22password%22:%22qwer@123%22%7D` resulted in a `400 BAD REQUEST` response:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Invalid J (truncated...)
```

I have copied the URL from error and run with the below command and I get HTTP status code 200 success response.

```
curl -X POST 'https://domain/api/res.partner/magento_update_partner_single?magento_id=28&odoo_email=mail@mail.com&data_json=%7B%22customer%22:%7B%22id%22:28,%22group_id%22:1,%22created_in%22:%22Default%20Store%20View%22,%22dob%22:%22string%22,%22email%22:%22mail@mail.com%22,%22firstname%22:%22Bilal%22,%22lastname%22:%22Usean%22,%22middlename%22:%22%22,%22store_id%22:1,%22website_id%22:1,%22addresses%22:%5B%7B%22id%22:113,%22customer_id%22:28,%22country_id%22:%22US%22,%22street%22:%5B%227000%20Central%20Parkway,%20Suite%20220%22%5D,%22telephone%22:%22+1%20678-648-7722%22,%22postcode%22:%2230328%22,%22city%22:%22Atlanta%22,%22region%22:%7B%22region_code%22:%22GA%22%7D,%22firstname%22:%22Bilal%20Usean%22,%22lastname%22:%22Bilal%20Usean%22,%22middlename%22:%22%22%7D%5D,%22disable_auto_group_change%22:0%7D,%22password%22:%22qwer@123%22%7D' -g -H "accept: application/json" -H "Access-Token: df729ade753cbe46789befae12344d72e9a7964d"
```

The curl command is working fine so URL query params are passed correctly but somehow it is failed in guzzle.

please advise me to fix this error in the guzzle.

Comment: The cURL command appears to have special characters properly URL-encoded, especially in the JSON part. With your guzzle request, you appear to have made no efforts in that regard, whatsoever.

Comment: _STOP_ assembling query strings manually; `http_build_query` exists.

Comment: URL encode your json in first example

Comment: @CBroe In the error log, it shows encoded format URL with 400 bad response so I think no further encode needs. By the way, just now I have tried with http_build_query and urlencode but no luck, the same bad request error is thrown.

Comment: I have checked with postman also I'm getting the same error for both "with encode" and "without encode", curl command only works

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine after changed the header as like curl

**From**

```
$headers = ['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json','Content-Type'     => 'application/json','Access-Token' => $access_token]];
```

**To**

```
$headers = ['headers' => ['accept' => 'application/json','Access-Token' => $access_token]];
```